# php: What is the value of 'code' in $_GET['code'] in youtube API

Tags: php, google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I am trying to pull out comments from a particular video from youtube data API, already i have authenticated the user in front end. After that I am calling my php REST api to fetch the comment for that particular video. However, I don't understand from where I will get the value of 'code'.

```
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {       
      $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
      $_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey] = $client->getAccessToken();
      //header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}
```

Comment: Who wrote this code?

Comment: This is just a sample code for experimental purpose, written by some interns

Comment: Try following this https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/url-shortener.php  once you get this to work you should understand what needs to be changed for youtube.   Your authentication flow is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a $_GET request.
So if you have a URL www.example.com/?code=value , then the $_GET['code'] is equal to "value".

So in your case you are looking for the authorised code.

```
 www.example.com/oauth2callback.php?state=authorise&code=4/gJwhPmFw_Mqfkdxz8R2Xyp..........
```

Look [[HERE]](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) for info on Oauth for YouTube